# How to make a user read a collection of all documents where documents.uid == user.uid in firebase flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase

Basically I have 2 collections 'Bookings' and 'Users'. The 'Bookings' collection contains all bookings created by every user, and the 'Users' collection displays information about the user.

```
User: {
    name:
    uid:
}

Bookings: {
   location:
   time:
   uid:
   etc:
}
```

I have a GetBookings() function that retrieves the 'Bookings' collection and display it for an admin account. However, I am currently stuck on how to approach displaying a user his bookings.

```
getBookings() {
  var bookings = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('bookings');
  return bookings.get();
}
```

I thought about creating another 'Bookings' collection under each user but am unsure on how to link this new 'Bookings' collection with the previous collection in order to preserve the same bookings id. I had a go with security rules as mentioned by @Renaud Tarnec, however I might be getting the syntax wrong, or during looping through the bookings collection and receiving a permission denied on our request it preemptively stops my fetchBookings() function, or a user might be able to access the entire 'Bookings' collection regardless of whether each booking has his uid or not.

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    
    // Allows users to view their bookings
    match /bookings/{booking} {
        allow read: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == booking.uid;
        allow write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

```
Future<List<BookingModel>> fetchBookings() async {
    var bookings = await _bookingRepository.fetchAllBookings();

    return bookings.map((snapshot) {
      var bookingMap = snapshot.data();
      return BookingModel(bookingMap['email'], bookingMap['location'], bookingMap['phoneNumber'],
          bookingMap['dateTime'], bookingMap['uid'], bookingMap['dateCreated']);
    }).toList();
  }
```

I'd like to know what would be professional/industrially accepted way in tackling this problem.

Comment: Just in case, I want you to know that `match /bookings/{booking}` {booking} is just a string, not an object. So it not has `booking.uid` field. You need to use `resource.data.uid` to get uid field.

Comment: I see, I must have misunderstood the wildcard explanation. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like I said, in my opinion, the best solution for you is to set correct rules in database and create correct queries to get that data.

Rules:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if false;
    }
    match /bookings/{docId} {
      allow read: if resource.data.uid == request.auth.uid || isAdmin()
      // bellow you can use second part after && but im not sure are it will be null or unassigned this is overenginered so you can just not use condition after &&.
      allow update: if resource.data.uid == request.auth.uid && request.resource.data.uid == null || isAdmin()
      allow create: if request.auth != null && request.resource.data.uid == request.auth.uid || isAdmin()
      allow delete: if isAdmin()
    }
  }
}

function isAdmin() {
    return request.auth.token.admin == true;
}
```

Queries you need to make for users:

```js
getBookings() {
  // Im not sure are it will work like that in flutter im not a flutter programmer.
  // You need to specify using where() method that you want documents with your uid or rules will not allow you to get eny data.
  var bookings = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('bookings').where('uid', '==', user.uid);
  return bookings.get();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I was just afraid that through these security rules a malicious user has access to the bookings collection, as long as he is an existing user.

Comment: @JoeyLeo Using that conditions only admins who have `admin = true` in his token/claims can do everything with every document and users can make every thing with their documents except deleting any document.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if: While you adding the booking data to the "Booking" collection, you also need to add it also to the user.booking collection.

Comment: I'm just confused on how to make their uids that are generated by firestore to be the same, so I'm able to update and reflect on both documents in the case a booking is cancelled for example.

Answer (score 0):

Since the `bookings` collection can only be accessed by an admin account, a classical solution in your case (denormalization in a NoSQL Database) is to use a [Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events) to create the Booking document in the `users/{userID}/bookings` subcollection when a new Booking is created in the `bookings` collection.

Something along the following lines:

```
exports.duplicateBooking = functions
    .firestore
    .document('bookings/{docId}')
    .onCreate((snap, context) => {

        const userId = ....; // Not clear from your question how you define that. You should probably add it to the booking doc.

        const bookingData = snap.data();

        return admin
            .firestore()
            .collection(`users/${userId}/bookings)
            .add({
                 'location': bookingData.location,
                 'time': bookingData.time, 
                 'email': bookingData.email,
                 'phoneNumber': bookingData.phoneNumber
          });

    });
```

---

Another possibilities would be to keep a unique `bookings` collection with a set of Security Rules that allows [a user to read his own bookings](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#authentication). In this case, remember that [rules are not filters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#rules_are_not_filters) when you write the corresponding query.

Comment: Hi Renaud, I think security rules would be the appropriate way in order to tackle my problem, however I am currently having issues with it. I've updated my question, and was wondering what would be the best way to approach my problem. Additionally, am I right to assume that using security rules this way might result in higher complexity and costs?

Comment: In my opinion, your second option will be easier and better in this situation. @JoeyLeo Setup correct rules in Firestore and create correct queries to get data from collection.